# Make ordered bootstrap column float at top of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tricky little problem I can't wrap my head around.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/KKczd/ for reference.

**Scenario:** I have two bootstrap ordered columns: On large screens, they sit next two each other, on smaller screens the one on the right flows above the left column.

```
<div class="row">
    <h1>Header section</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9" id="right">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3" id="left">...</div>
</div>
```

This basic layout and functionality works perfectly.

**Goal:**
For large screens, when the page scrolls down, I want the right column to stay on the top of the page at all times. For small screens, I want the right column (now the first row) to stay on top with content scrolling underneath it as the content scrolls up.

**Problem:**
I've written some javascript that only seems to make the right column get lower and lower - and it has no impact on the section on smaller screen widths - except some magical disappearing.

I have played with offset, and resetting offset, I have also tried using some css positioning but it just gets hackier and hackier. Also, I'm trying to use as many default bootstrap styles as possible, and as few positioning hacks as possible.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Question: on your JavaScript code, why do you use Math.max and not Math.min?

Comment: So you pretty much want a fixed position right column on large screens to stay on the right hand side and then on small screens, to stay fixed on the top of the yellow div?

Comment: Yes, I think that summarizes it.

Answer (score 0):

Goal:

{1}[For large screens, when the page scrolls down, I want the right column to stay on the top of the page at all times].

{2}[For small screens, I want the right column (now the first row) to stay on top with content scrolling underneath it as the content scrolls up.]

In bootstrap [website](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-normalize) itself they used your required concept for {1} use the class = 'affix' for the right column,

For {2} , I have an idea for that, Create one navbar at the top of the screen and set the class = 'navbar-default navbar-fixed-top visible-xs visible-sm hidden-lg hidden-md' and give the same right column content in that navbar also, In column right use the class = 'visible-lg visible-md hidden-sm hidden-xs'. When the screen size reaches small screen, it hides the content of right column, and shows the navbar content at the top.

Hope this will be useful, Thank you.